# How to push pages to MasterDetailPage using Mvvm

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I want to use `Mvvm`(Basic Mvvm) for `MasterDetailPage` development. But facing issue to push new `ContentPage` to `Detail`

If I am using *code behind* than no issue, I can do like below

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  Detail=  new NavigationPage(new Menu1Page());
}
```

But when it comes to `Mvvm` in *ViewModel* I don't have **Detail** page access there. So I can this, but it is hiding `MasterDetailPage`

```
async Task Menu1Page()
{
   await Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new Menu1Page());
}
```

So, how can push pages to `Detail` from Mvvm?

Comment: this wpf( still xaml) sample might help the understanding of the concept `separation of concerns`:https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/332615/WPF-Master-Details-MVVM-Application

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access `Detail` page too in ViewModel. Just you need to cast `App.Current.MainPage` as `MasterDetailPage`. Look at code below.

```
async Task NavigateNext()
{
   await (App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(new Menu1Page());
   //(App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).IsPresented = false;
}
```

The above code snippet pushing pages as child of `MasterDetailPage` so that you can go back by pressing back arrow on `Navigationbar`.

You can set pages directly to `Detail` page, it shows pages at a first page of `MasterDetailPage` in this scenario back arrow wont be available to go back, like below

```
(App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).Detail = new NavigationPage(new Menu1Page());
//(App.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).IsPresented = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, no.

You need to define `BindingContext` for the page, and use code-behind navigation.

Or use `NavigationService`, more details [Enterprise App Navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/navigation)

Or use any Mvvm framework for this.

Comment: After defining `BindingContext`, using code behind not giving me any help. Ultimately I would be on same situation.